# how to set tag description in _arguments (zsh completion)

Tags: zsh

When using `zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%d'`, I see short headlines above completion options.

In a short example this looks like

```
prompt% function _myfun1() { _arguments '--debug[print some debug]' '--quiet[do not print stuff]'}
prompt% compdef _myfun1 myfun1
prompt% myfun1⇥
option:
--debug  -- print some debug
--quiet  -- do not print stuff
```

When using `_describe` this description can be specified `_describe -t tagname "description" arraywithoptions`. Can I override `_argument`'s default `option` with a different description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override it for anything using `options` as a tag which may be rather more than just those added by `_arguments`.

`zstyle ':completion:*:options:descriptions' format '%Boverriden option%b'`

Comment: I guess I could insert `_myfun1` to only use the overriden option in this one case (`zstyle ':completion:myfun1:*:options:descriptions' format '%Boverriden option%b'` ). Though this only works when I use `_myfun1` to complete `myfun1` but not when I call `_myfun1` from anywhere else. I should've been clearer, I want to write a different description for that one instance of `_arguments`.

Comment: The second component of the zstyle context is for the completion widget so you shouldn't stuff your function name in there. There's no way to give `_arguments` a different tag. Your only option is to do without it and use `_describe` which I wouldn't really recommend.